# Order of loading during Spring Java Config

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, config

I have a Java Config class that looks similar to:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private MyRegistry registry;

    public CustomAttributeConfig() {
        . . .
    }

    @Bean
    public IBeanApiType someBeanApi() {
       return new SomeBeanApi();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructionCodeHere() {
        registry.register(someBeanApi());
    }
    . . .
```

Is the order of execution of the `@Autowired`, `@Bean`, and `@PostConstruct` guaranteed in any way?
What if the `@Bean` used the `@Autowired` registry value?

The order of execution I am seeing in my real code is:

1. the autowired field
2. the @PostConstruct annotated method
3. the @Bean annotated method

My goal is to have 2 and 3 to execute in reverse order.  How do I know the order of mixtures of these annotations in a Java Config file and what options are available to control that order?

**EDITTED!**
Thought about this some more and while I am interested in the order, that may not really be critical.  I modified the code above slightly to reflect the fact that I want to call the @Bean constructor from the @PostConstruct code.

This seems to work fine for the very limited tests I have done.  Does anyone know if all the necessary Spring initialization is guaranteed to be finished when a @PostConstruct is called such that calling an @Bean annotated method will always work?  I did step into the calls and see the interceptors being invoked, but I don't know that the proxy I will get back will always be the "right" one, with all the advisors, advice, etc properly attached.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the current construct where you are using bean creation method, Spring will ensure that this method returns created bean. And of course ensures that the bean is properly initialized

Comment: Except this doesn't really work all the time.  When one has lots of config classes across multiple projects, 'someBeanApi' _can_ get referenced causing it be to constructed prior to the "MyConfig" bean (which does the autowire).  Thus the PostConstruct executes before the autowire.  There is no "guarantee".  However, while I have seen a few times, I have never been able to reproduce in a standalone manner to submit as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can have following code inside your SomeBeanApi rather than MyConfig

```
   @Autowired(required = true)
    private MyRegistry registry;

   @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructionCodeHere() {
        registry.register(this);
    }
```